# How to allow CommonJS programs to import from my TypeScript library without using require().default and having autocomplete in text editors

Tags: node.js, typescript, node-modules, commonjs

I'm currently developing a TypeScript library to be used internally in my company's projects, which are a mix of JavaScript and TypeScript Node applications.

So, I want to be able to import the library's default class properly in JavaScript with CommonJS. However, I can only use my class in these programs if I import it with `require('...').default`.

I managed to make it work previously by adding a `module.exports = MyClass` at the end of the file, but the autocomplete of VSCode doesn't seem to catch up to that, still suggesting the default before showing the methods.

How can I make it so I can import my class by just using `require('...')` while still making sure the autocomplete is properly working?

Thanks.

EDIT:

For clarity, what I want to do is to be able to do this:

```js
const MyClass = require('MyTypeScriptClass');
```

instead of:

```js
const MyClass = require('MyTypeScriptClass').default;
```

### Edit

I decided to not use `export default` when exporting from a library, since it seems to be what every other library does.

Answer (score 0):

The TypeScript equivalent should be this:

```
class MyClass {
}

export = MyClass
```

Can also be inlined to `export = class MyClass { ...` if that is preferred.

(To import an export like this in a TypeScript project you need to set the `esModuleInterop` flag.)

Comment: I've tried doing this, but it still asks for me to use use `require().default`.

I've added an edit to make my intentions clearer.

Comment: @Asghwor Adjusted the answer.